# Python, Pygame List Conundrum

Tags: python, pygame

I am incredibly stuck, I'm using Python and Pygame to make a game project. (screen is 770 x 485)
It involves moving a circle left or right through 5 vertical lanes as randomly generated rectangles drop down. I have a Wall class for generating them randomly but I do not know how to detect collision between EACH instance of the rectangle and my circle.

Right in the bit with z and the c list is where I ATTEMPT to try and make them collide but it only collides with the first rectangle and it does not detect any other falling rectangles (which are generated after a period of 100 ticks between each other)
Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm really not sure about the z variable, c list and v variable :\

Thanks in advance!

```
class Wall:
    def __init__(self,colour,x,y,life):
        self.colour = colour
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.life = life
    def drop(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, (self.x, self.y, 154, 30))
        self.y += 1.25
        self.life -= 1
        if self.life < 0:
            wall.remove(self)

def playMode(): #assume everything is indented properly
global wall, points
check   = True
left    = False
right   = False
circlex = 385
degrees = 0
health  = 3
wall = []
x = 2
points = 0
n = 0
c = []
starttime = time.time()
while True:
    runningtime = time.clock()
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    x -= 1
    if x == 1:
      wall.append(Wall((random.randint(1,255),random.randint(1,255),random.randint(1,255)),
random.choice([0, 154, 308, 462, 616]), -30 , 450))
        x = 100
    for i in wall:
        i.drop()
    z = wall[-1]
    c.append(z)
    v = c[(n)]
    if 445 >= v.y >= 340 and v.x == (circlex - 77):           
        health -= 1
        points -= 5
        v.y = 485 #moves this instance offscreen so it doesn't make the hp go to 0 immediately
        n += 1
        print v.y

    circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, colour,(circlex, 409), 50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                showPauseScreen()
            elif event.key == K_p:
                showPauseScreen()
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                if circlex > 77:
                    circlex = circlex - 154
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                if circlex < 616:
                    circlex = circlex + 154
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            terminate()

    if health == 0:
        check = False
        return #goes to gameover screen basically
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)
```

Comment: Please format your code according to Pythonic conventions before we can help you.

Comment: we cannot help you, if you do not indent correctly, from a first glance though, you are onlu checking the collision on one object - z[-1].

Comment: Pygame has built in collision detection (for rects). Have a look at this question for an idea of how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227616/how-to-use-sprite-collide-in-pygame

Comment: Pygame also has built in sprite Group classes.  They make it easy to detect collision with any sprite in the group.

Answer (score 1):

You could just look at pygame documentation, but basically you want to use this function, which will return a bool of whether or not one sprite is colliding with another:

```
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(<sprite>,<group>,False)     #in almost all circumstances the third argument should be False. This will check for collision between a sprite and group.
```

For more information, check the pygame docs:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide