# I created a flappybird clone but I can't make collision between bird and pot body pot head

Tags: pygame, collision

I used random range for my pots and I don't know how to make collision between pots and bird. I can't use pipe codes because its a project and I should create it with pots I wrote a simple crash def for know that collision happened. I don't know how take pot range

```
pygame.init()
#displayset
display_width = 600
display_height = 300
high_pot = display_height * 0.80
low_pot = display_height * 0.20
half_pot_gap = 50

#object
birdImg = pygame.image.load('bird.png')
bird_height = 80
bird_width = 80
x = 50
y = (display_height * 0.5) - (bird_height/2)

#colors
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)
skyblue = (135,206,235)
orange = (255,69,0)

#deeeeeef
def bird(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(birdImg,(x,y))
    

    
    
def pot(pot1X,pot1Y,pot1H,pot2X,pot2Y,pot2H,potW,potColor):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,potColor,(pot1X,pot1Y,potW,pot1H))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black,(pot1X,pot1Y,potW,pot1H),2)
    
    
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,potColor,(pot2X,pot2Y,potW,pot2H))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black,(pot2X,pot2Y,potW,pot2H),2)
    
    pot_head_1X = pot1X - 10
    pot_head_1Y = pot1H
    pot_head_2X = pot2X - 10
    pot_head_2Y = pot2Y
    pot_head_width = 50
    pot_head_height = 20
    
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,orange,(pot_head_1X,pot_head_1Y,pot_head_width,pot_head_height))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black,(pot_head_1X,pot_head_1Y,pot_head_width,pot_head_height),2)
    
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,orange,(pot_head_2X,pot_head_2Y,pot_head_width,pot_head_height))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black,(pot_head_2X,pot_head_2Y,pot_head_width,pot_head_height),2)
    
    
def new_pot(factor):
    new_random = random.randrange(low_pot,high_pot)
    pot1H = new_random - half_pot_gap
    pot1X = display_width + 100 * factor
    pot1Y = 0
    
    pot2H = display_height - (new_random + half_pot_gap)
    pot2X = display_width + 100 * factor
    pot2Y = new_random + half_pot_gap
    
    
    return pot1X,pot1Y,pot1H,pot2X,pot2Y,pot2H

#scoredef

def display_message(textMessage, tColor, position_X, position_Y):
    textMessage = str(textMessage)
    font_and_size = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",22)
    text_surface = font_and_size.render(textMessage, True, tColor)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = ((position_X),(position_Y))
    gameDisplay.blit(text_surface,text_rect)
#pot
potW = 30
potColor = yellow
gameSpeed = 3

pot1X = [0,0,0,0]
pot1Y = [0,0,0,0]
pot1H = [0,0,0,0]
pot2X = [0,0,0,0]
pot2Y = [0,0,0,0]
pot2H = [0,0,0,0]

pot1X[0],pot1Y[0],pot1H[0],pot2X[0],pot2Y[0],pot2H[0] = new_pot(1)
pot1X[1],pot1Y[1],pot1H[1],pot2X[1],pot2Y[1],pot2H[1] = new_pot(3)
pot1X[2],pot1Y[2],pot1H[2],pot2X[2],pot2Y[2],pot2H[2] = new_pot(5)
pot1X[3],pot1Y[3],pot1H[3],pot2X[3],pot2Y[3],pot2H[3] = new_pot(6.5)

score = 0
score_counter = 0

def crash():
    display_message("YOU CRASHED" ,red,50, 50)

#window
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Racey")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

tasadof = False
y_change = 0

space_flag = 0
down = True
while not tasadof:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            tasadof = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                y_change = -9
                space_flag = 0
                down = False
                
                
    if not down:
        if y_change<0:
            if y-1 > - 10:
                y -= 1
            else:
                y= -10
            y_change+=1
            space_flag = 0
        else:
            down = True
            space_flag = 0
    else:
        y += 2
        if y> (display_height-(bird_height-20)):
            y = display_height-(bird_height-20)
    y += y_change            
    gameDisplay.fill(skyblue)
    bird(x,y)      
    for i in range(4):
        pot(pot1X[i],pot1Y[i],pot1H[i],pot2X[i],pot2Y[i],pot2H[i],potW,potColor)
        pot1X[i] -= gameSpeed
        pot2X[i] -= gameSpeed
        if pot1X[i] < -50 :
            pot1X[i],pot1Y[i],pot1H[i],pot2X[i],pot2Y[i],pot2H[i] = new_pot(1)
            score += 5
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)
    
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention that it would be better to add more detail to your question. More specifically add some comments explaining whats going on in your code. By doing that, more people will answer.

Now, collision in Pygame is super easy... if you use SPRITES!!! The idea is that you make a group of sprites, which is pretty much a fancy list of the pipes and the bird. Then you just check if anything in that list is colliding, there is a simple method to do all that. Here are a few links to get you started:

Sprites/Pygame lessons: https://kidscancode.org/blog/tags/pygame/

How to do Sprite Collision detection: [How to Use Sprite Collide in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227616/how-to-use-sprite-collide-in-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

You have the position and dimensions of the bird and you have the position and dimensions of the pots. It should be fairly straightforward to write code that loops over the pots to see if those areas overlap with the area occupied by the bird and you have a collision.

It would make it easier if you reworked your code to use pygames Rect class (docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)) to hold the position and size of the object since then you could use the Rect builtin [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) method.

You could go further and use pygames [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) class and make your game even simpler.

Lastly, it is better to keep all of the information related to an individual object, like a pot, together in a individual instance of that object, like a pot class, rather than keep all the x values for them together in a list and all the heights together in another list (etc), like you are doing in the separate `POT1X` and `POT1H` lists.  Using Sprites would implicitly do that since you would extend the Sprite class for each object type. One for the bird and one for the pots, though you do not actually have to use Sprites to make the move to using objects/classes for your game objects, you could just make your own classes.

EDIT:

It is fairly straightforward to determine if two areas overlap in any portion.
personally I would not do it this way. I would use `pygame.Rect`'s to contain the information about the rectangles and then use [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect). However it is important to know how to determine if two areas overlap. You have to check where the rectangles edges are with respect to one another.

Assuming that r1_x and r1_y is the top right corner of rect1 and that r1_w and r1_w are the width and height, and similarly for r2_x, r2_y, r2_w, r2_h, then:

```py
def rect_collision_check(r1_x, r1_y, r1_w, r1_h, r2_x, r2_y, r2_w, r2_h):
    if ((r1_x + r1_w < r2_x) or (r1_x > r2_x + r2_w) or
        (r1_y + r1_h < r2_y) or (r1_y > r2_y + r2_h)):
        return False
    return True
```

Or just returning the logical result directly:

```py
def rect_collision_check(r1_x, r1_y, r1_w, r1_h, r2_x, r2_y, r2_w, r2_h):
    return not ((r1_x + r1_w < r2_x) or (r1_x > r2_x + r2_w) or
                (r1_y + r1_h < r2_y) or (r1_y > r2_y + r2_h))
```

Loop over the pots calling the above function with the bird info and the pot info. If you get True return you had a collision.

Comment: you mean i change all my POTS to sprite?

Comment: can you help me to create a collision with these pots and not changing them cause its for a project and i should make it like that i all i need is collision part to complete that

Comment: @Little_DOGH I added an edit to show how to check for overlapping areas. Hope that helps you.